# MLAG with four links active

Tags: lag

Say you have a server with two NICs each with two 25g ports, and you have two L2 switches. Can you use MLAG to achieve four times the bandwidth with all links active at the same time?

Edit:
The switches are either Dell EMC Power Switch Z9100-ON or Z9264F-ON, the NICs are Mellanox ConnectX-6 Dx.

Comment: Please add the switch type to your question. Are the switches stacked?

Comment: I'm just validating a design for a new hardware, the switches are not stacked, and they configured with MLAG, and there is a link between them. similar to number 4 in [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multi-chassis_link_aggregation_group), but with two links, totaling in four links from server to switch pair.

Comment: the vendor is dell if that is relevant.

Comment: Vendor *and* model, please....

Comment: I have reached out to dell and the answer is yes.

Comment: Good job - you should add the relevant configuration details and make that an answer.

Comment: We are still working with dell to iron out the rest of the details, but I am not sure how are things will be configured. They just confirmed that it will work. An alternative to this was doing routing on the hosts. I don't think I can provide any details right now, as it will take several months to get things set up.